# how to trigger an event when embedded vimeo video starts to play

Tags: javascript, events, vimeo

I have written a slider which includes a vimeo embedded video one of it's slides. How can I stop my slider to auto_next() when a user push the play button of vimeo video player?

I know how to stop my slides as you can guess, but i don't know how to listen vimeo's play event.

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Froogaloop library.  Here is a link to download:
https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript

There is a detailed example of using it on the Vimeo developer website under the section "Calling the API with Froogaloop":
http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api